# .render() TypeError: the first argument must be callable

Tags: python, pandas

Someone graciously helped me create the following beautifully formatted table ([from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75560887/how-to-format-and-color-monetary-numbers-in-pandas-dataframe/75566540?noredirect=1#comment133357735_75566540)):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import locale


money = [10000000, 2200000000, 10241100000.4521, 20224400000.75895]
honey = [30.6427984591421, 9584.28792256921, 37008.6603, 211200.2304295]
ltrs = ["a", "b", "a", "c"]
YRMO = ["202211", "202210", "202211", "202210"]
org = ['Main','Main', 'Jr', 'Jr']
df = pd.DataFrame(
    zip(money, honey, ltrs, YRMO, org), columns=["money", "honey", "ltrs", "YRMO", "org"]
)

YRMOs = sorted(set(df["YRMO"]))

pivot = df.pivot_table(
    values=["money", "honey"],
    index="ltrs",
    columns=["YRMO"],
    aggfunc={"money": np.sum, "honey": np.sum},
    margins=True,
    margins_name="Total",
)
pivot = pivot.drop("Total", axis=1, level=1)
pivot = pivot.fillna(0)

pivot["Var 1"] = pivot["money"][max(YRMOs)] - pivot["money"][min(YRMOs)]
pivot["Var 2"] = pivot["honey"][max(YRMOs)] - pivot["honey"][min(YRMOs)]

def color(val):
    global color
    if val[0] == '$' and float(val[1:].replace(",", "")) >1000:
        color = 'red'
    else:
        color = 'green'
    return f'color: {color}'

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "us_US.UTF-8")

pivot = pivot.applymap(lambda x: locale.currency(val=x, grouping=True, symbol=True)).apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(pat=r"\.\d{2}",repl="", regex=True))

pivot = pivot.style.applymap(color, subset=['Var 1', 'Var 2'])

html_pivot = pivot.render()
```

But if I apply the same logic/functions to a subsequent, different table/dataframe in the same program, like so:

```
pivot2 = df[df['org'] == 'Jr'].pivot_table(
    values=["money", "honey"], 
    index="ltrs", 
    columns=['YRMO'], 
    aggfunc={"money": np.sum, "honey": np.sum},
    margins = True,
    margins_name = 'Total'
)

pivot2 = pivot2.drop("Total", axis=1, level=1)
pivot2 = pivot2.fillna(0)


pivot2["Var 1"] = pivot2["money"][max(YRMOs)] - pivot2["money"][min(YRMOs)]
pivot2["Var 2"] = pivot2["honey"][max(YRMOs)] - pivot2["honey"][min(YRMOs)]

pivot2 = pivot2.applymap(lambda x: locale.currency(val=x, grouping=True, symbol=True)).apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(pat=r"\.\d{2}",repl="", regex=True))


pivot2 = pivot2.style.applymap(color, subset=['Var 1', 'Var 2'])#\

html_pivot = pivot2.render()
```

I get the following when I try to render() the second table in the program:

TypeError: the first argument must be callable

Appreciate any help understanding and troubleshooting the error.

I am formatting and rendering these tables to send in an html email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `applymap` on `pivot2`, the `color` variable you're passing as an argument points to a **string**, not the **function color**, hence the error messaging saying `applymap` accepts only a callable.

Your code works fine if you remove `global color` in your function `color` and / or avoid using the same `color` name for different objects, which leads to [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

I would recommend doing both, like this:

```py
def color_for(val):
    if val[0] == "$" and float(val[1:].replace(",", "")) > 1000:
        color = "red"
    else:
        color = "green"
    return f"color: {color}"

...
pivot = pivot.style.applymap(color_for, subset=["Var 1", "Var 2"])

...
pivot2 = pivot2.style.applymap(color_for, subset=["Var 1", "Var 2"])
```